# Tailwind css not work on Vercel after build and deploy it

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS to style my web app, In local, it works perfectly but when I build my GitHub repository and deploy it on Vercel, it does not work, where is the problem with this?

one of my col:

```
<div
        className={`${classes.allTechnicalList} flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center px-0`}
 >
<Col
   lg={2}
   md={6}
   sm={6}
   xs={12}
   className={`lg:px-0.5 md:pr-0 md:pl-8 py-4 ${classes.allTechnicalListCol}`}
        >
   <div className="imgBorder text-center rounded-lg shadow  block flex-wrap justify-center items-center px-5 pt-8 pb-16 lg:mb-12 h-44 lg:w-48">
      <Image
          className="max-w-full h-full m-auto"
          alt=""
          src="/php-icon.png"
       />
       <p className="text-sm space-x-1 m-0 pt-2 pb-4">PHP</p>
    </div>
 </Col>
  .
  .
  .
```

In local:
[image]

After build and deploy it on Vercel:
[image]

As you see, in local the `col` display is `flex` but on the server, it is not.

This is my taiwlind config:

```
module.exports = {
purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*. 
{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
theme: {
extend: {
  transitionDuration: ["hover", "focus"],
},
fontSize: {
  sm: ["15px"],
  base: ["16px", "24px"],
  lg: ["25px", "28px"],
  xl: "40px",
},
},
variants: {
extend: {},
},
corePlugins: {
  container: false,
},
plugins: [
 function ({ addComponents }) {
  addComponents({
    ".container": {
      maxWidth: "100%",
      "@screen sm": {
        maxWidth: "600px",
      },
      "@screen md": {
        maxWidth: "765px",
      },
      "@screen lg": {
        maxWidth: "1320px",
      },
      "@screen xl": {
        maxWidth: "1320px",
      },
    },
  });
},
],
};
```

this is postccs.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
plugins: [
"tailwindcss",
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
[
  "postcss-preset-env",
  {
    autoprefixer: {
      flexbox: "no-2009",
    },
    stage: 3,
    features: {
      "custom-properties": false,
    },
  },
],
],
};
```

Comment: Can you share your `tailwind` and `postcss` config (if present)?

Comment: @brc-dd I added them both.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue if your run the prod build locally with `next build && next start`?

Comment: It says this page could not found

Answer (score 2):

Replace `purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"]` by `purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./Components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"]` (components should have the 'C' capital)

Comment: It worked. Awesome. A simple one!! 

Searched / tried quite a lot of options..

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you included tailwind as a devdependency.
2. Check if there's any error like variables being undefined which is causing something not rendered.

Comment: All thing is correct

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your project is based on React.

You can't "npm run start" to compile assets in real-time on the server, you can only do this on localhost.
Instead, you have to run "npm run build" and deploy the resulting build folder with compiled assets on the server.

You should deploy just the "build" folder on the server and no other file.

Also, be sure to review the Tailwindcss installation process entirely to make sure that you changed scripts to correctly include Tailwind, here's a link to the official documentation (Reactjs section): https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Bonus: clear server cache, maybe is the only thing you have to do.

Comment: My project is based on next.js and I build my Github repository by vercel, so it does it automatically.

Comment: Are you using Tailwind JIT mode?

Comment: No, I don't use it.  Should I do?

Comment: Just some style not work, some of them work, in here ``flex`` not work

Comment: You could temporarily switch to JIT mode in order to see if that works with your Continuous Deployment configuration with Vercel.

BTW I was checking your tailwind config file and I think there's an error with theme.extend, please check this page https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme.

Comment: I added jit mode, but the problem still exist

Comment: At this point, you should check the compiled CSS file and be sure that the classes used are present. If the classes are not present you should check if there's an update of tailwind or postcss package

Answer (score 0):

- check if tailwind is included in dependencies not devDependencies
- run npm build once and see if there is a problem in the build
- check tailwind docs and confirm you have tailwind config files with purge mode the way they recommend like:

````
module.exports = {
  purge: [
   // "./src/**/*.html",
   // "./src/**/*.vue,
   // "./src/**/*.jsx"
  ],
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}```
````

Comment: I checked all, there is not any thing wrong with them

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because of [purging](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production), tailwind has a feature where it purges out classes which aren't used in the project.

To verify if this is the case, and to *rule out* Vercel as the point of issue you can:

1. Create a new export using `npm run build && npm run export`
2. Serve the export, you can either do this by using a simple http server or tools like [hot-reload-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-hot-reload-server)
3. Test it out locally

If you see the same classes missing locally as well then it is for sure caused by the following line;

```
{`lg:px-0.5 md:pr-0 md:pl-8 py-4 ${classes.allTechnicalListCol}`}
```

You see when you load css as a module(*next.js feature*), if you then use concatenation to generate a dynamic string mixed of moduleClasses and static classes, tailwind misses that dynamic import, since it doesn't understand how next.js builds a random classname for each file imported as a module, if you inspect any next.js dom, you'll see your classes having their name attached with some hash/random string.

If you import a file called LoginPage.scss and use it's loginButton class,

```
import loginStyles from 'styles/LoginPage.scss'

function fun() {
  return <>
    <button className={loginStyles.loginButton}>Login</button>
  </>
}
```

The class that will be generated by next will look something like `LoginPage_LoginButton__1Auw8`, basically `{moduleName}_{className}_{randomString}`.

In order to fix this; you need to have a single module class attached to each className prop, so that tailwind can infer the classes properly, break the static classes and module class into two different divs applying the styles accordingly.

```
<!-- wrong method -->
<div className={`mx-auto font-lato ${myModule.myClass}`}></div>
```

```
<!-- right method, use encapsulating divs to have one moduleClass passed as a single prop -->
<div className={`mx-auto font-lato`}>
  <div className={myModule.myClass}>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case these classes **have to** be applied to the same div, consider creating a new class inside your style module and just import it directly.

Read more about writing [purgeble HTML](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html)

Comment: I removed all ``${classse.className}`` but the problem not solved.

Comment: Could you inspect the DOM and check which classes are loaded to the elements?

Comment: Also, is the local build working?

Comment: These classes ``lg:px-0.5 md:pr-0 md:pl-8 inline-flex py-4 col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12`` and also build working in local whiteout any problem

Comment: if I add those classes so it look like ``lg:px-0.5 md:pr-0 md:pl-8 py-4 tools_allTechnicalListCol__1o8IQ col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12``

Comment: in both of them when i run ``npm run build`` there is not any error.

Comment: when I run ``npm run build`` there is not any error but after if i run ``npm start`` it says this page could not found.

Comment: What happends when you do `npm run export`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@import "xxxx.css";
@tailwind utilities;
```

I put custom .css file before `@tailwind utilities;` and the style display normal. I'm also curious as to why this works. Brothers who know it can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in `module.exports` in `tailwind.config.js`:

```
important: true
```

Answer (score 0):

*if you are facing this issue in nextjs*

**Navigate to tailwind.config.ts and replace the line below
and replace the content**

```
  content: [
    "./Components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
```